# Problems connecting using MongoDB Compass

Tags: database, authentication, mongodb, authorization, roles

I'm trying to see the contents of a collection using MongoDB Compass. I have username/password authentication set up. I can log in successfully but can't see any documents in the collection. Instead, I see the error:

> An error occurred while loading navigation: command hostInfo requires
>   authentication.

Here are the list of roles the user has:

```
 "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "moviesDB"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "dbAdmin",
                        "db" : "moviesDB"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "dbOwner",
                        "db" : "moviesDB"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "clusterMonitor",
                        "db" : "admin"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "dbAdmin",
                        "db" : "moviesDB"
                }
        ]
```

I can successfully query the collection using mongo shell and node.js driver but not through Compass. 
If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the number one cause of simple auth issues through MongoDB administration apps such as 3T and Compass is in properly specifying the authentication database. Make sure that the authentication database of the user that you are attempting to log in as is properly set.

Beyond this, it would take some screenshots from the Compass login settings to provide more insight. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kevin!
I'm specifying the same db that I used to create the user. Here's a screenshot of parameters that I use: http://prntscr.com/kjvo2f

Comment: Two other ideas to try. They may not work but always worth the effort.

Comment: Have you tried setting auth db to admin? Can you give the user temporary cluster clusterAdmin roles to see if the issue is in accessing some type of server level metadata?

Comment: Setting auth db to admin doesn't work if the user was created for a different DB. I've just tried creating the same user for admin DB, granting him the same roles + the clusterAdmin role, but still got the same error =(

Comment: When you login via the shell, are you on the same machine that you are trying to run Compass from?

Comment: I wasn't but I just tried to do it from the same machine and connected using shell successfully

Comment: When you "login via the shell", are you using ssh to go to the server then running mongo OR are you running mongo from a shell on the same machine as the Compass app. The reason I ask is that you have to be able to access port 27017 explicitly for the machine that you are trying to run Compass from

Comment: I'm running mongo shell (with the --host option) on the same machine as Compass

Comment: Well. The only other idea I have is to grab some other third party tool such as Studio3T and see if that can connect. A for effort upvotes appreciated!

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward to hearing how you end up solving this one...

Comment: Try running this command from the mongo shell...[link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.hostInfo)

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately, from the shell it runs successfully.